# OpenServer ошибка запуска MySql-8.0

Tags: mysql, openserver

возникла ошибка при запуске OpenServer. Была такая же проблема в прошлый раз, но тогда был вирусняк, поэтому пришлось переустановить - все заработало. Но вот спустя месяц снова та же проблема. Ошибка на запуске модуля MySql8.0-Win10.

Вот лог этого модуля:

```
2024-01-13T13:48:32.282760Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] c:\ospanel\modules\database\MySQL-8.0-Win10\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 16864
2024-01-13T13:48:32.289413Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013907] [InnoDB] Deprecated configuration parameters innodb_log_file_size and/or innodb_log_files_in_group have been used to compute innodb_redo_log_capacity=67108864. Please use innodb_redo_log_capacity instead.
2024-01-13T13:48:32.291806Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-01-13T13:48:33.256892Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-01-13T13:48:33.573202Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: dict0dict.cc:3481:for_table || ref_table thread 24372
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
13:48:33 UTC - mysqld got exception 0x16 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Thread pointer: 0x1ec5fecb110
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
7ff7bf470858    mysqld.exe!?my_print_stacktrace@@YAXPEBEK@Z()
7ff7be60e92b    mysqld.exe!?print_fatal_signal@@YAXH@Z()
7ff7be60e6f3    mysqld.exe!?my_server_abort@@YAXXZ()
7ff7bf4547fa    mysqld.exe!?my_abort@@YAXXZ()
7ff7bf69ca99    mysqld.exe!?deallocate@?$allocator@V?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QEAAXQEAV?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@2@_K@Z()
7ff7bf5e982b    mysqld.exe!?deallocate@?$allocator@V?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QEAAXQEAV?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@2@_K@Z()
7ff7bf6b7fb1    mysqld.exe!?deallocate@?$allocator@V?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QEAAXQEAV?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@2@_K@Z()
7ff7bf6b788c    mysqld.exe!?deallocate@?$allocator@V?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QEAAXQEAV?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@2@_K@Z()
7ff7bf6a3c8e    mysqld.exe!?deallocate@?$allocator@V?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QEAAXQEAV?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@2@_K@Z()
7ff7bf6a1d85    mysqld.exe!?deallocate@?$allocator@V?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QEAAXQEAV?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@2@_K@Z()
7ff7bf6b8506    mysqld.exe!?deallocate@?$allocator@V?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QEAAXQEAV?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@2@_K@Z()
7ff7bf6b950d    mysqld.exe!?deallocate@?$allocator@V?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QEAAXQEAV?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@2@_K@Z()
7ff7bf6b8e2e    mysqld.exe!?deallocate@?$allocator@V?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QEAAXQEAV?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@2@_K@Z()
7ff7bf647d1a    mysqld.exe!?deallocate@?$allocator@V?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QEAAXQEAV?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@2@_K@Z()
7ff7bf6321f8    mysqld.exe!?deallocate@?$allocator@V?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QEAAXQEAV?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@2@_K@Z()
7ff7bf632b35    mysqld.exe!?deallocate@?$allocator@V?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QEAAXQEAV?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@2@_K@Z()
7ff7bf54082c    mysqld.exe!?set_compression_level@Zstd_comp@compression@transaction@binary_log@@UEAAXI@Z()
7ff7bf3db4b6    mysqld.exe!?init@Rpl_info_values@@QEAA_NXZ()
7ff7bf3dfbc6    mysqld.exe!?init@Rpl_info_values@@QEAA_NXZ()
7ff7bf30df6e    mysqld.exe!?init@Rpl_info_values@@QEAA_NXZ()
7ff7bf309542    mysqld.exe!?init@Rpl_info_values@@QEAA_NXZ()
7ff7be46d1fe    mysqld.exe!?run_bootstrap_thread@bootstrap@@YA_NPEBDPEAUMYSQL_FILE@@P6A_NPEAVTHD@@@ZW4enum_thread_type@@@Z()
7ff7bf8a87a9    mysqld.exe!?deallocate@?$allocator@V?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QEAAXQEAV?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@2@_K@Z()
7ff7bf46139c    mysqld.exe!?my_thread_self_setname@@YAXPEBD@Z()
7ffec6441bb2    ucrtbase.dll!_configthreadlocale()
7ffec75a7344    KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
7ffec8ac26b1    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0): 
Connection ID (thread ID): 1
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

Если кто сталкивался с данной проблемой, помогите плис) А то переустанавливать заново не хочется и времени не много.

Восстановить через

```
[mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery = 1
```

также пробовал, давало доступ только при значении 4, но нельзя же все время в режиме восставновления работать.